# Loading gif image in jsp not animating

Tags: java, jsp, button, gif

I added a loading gif in my JSP to be displayed after clicking on a button while the servlet is running. the problem is that the gif is fix and not animating on Eclipse and Google Chrome.
Here is my code:

```
<form action="search " method="post">
    Informationt: <input type="text" name="information"
        size="30">
    <input type="submit" value="Search"
        onclick="document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';">
    <img id="loader" src="images/loader.gif" style="display: none; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
    width: 100px; height: 100px; " />   
</form>
```

In CSS,

```
#loader { }
```

Is there a way to make it run?

Comment: And your GIF is where? How can we know what's wrong with it?

Comment: thank you, you were right! For some reason, the gif I downloaded stopped animating, so it is not a java problem.